# Comparing entropies $H((f(X,Y), g(X,Y)))$ and $H ((f(X,Y),g(X,Z)))$

Tags: inequality, boolean-algebra, information-theory, entropy

Let X,Y,Z be three independent uniform distributions on $\{0,1\}^n$; $f, g:\{0,1\}^n\times\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ be two boolean functions. Is it true that

$$H((f(X,Y), g(X,Y)))\leq H ((f(X,Y),g(X,Z)))$$

where $H(\cdot)$ represents the Shannon entropy

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_1 = [X \ \ Y]$ and $X_2 = [X \ \ Z]$.

Then $$H(f(X_1),g(X_1)) = H(f(X_1)) + H(g(X_1)|f(X_1))\\
H(f(X_1),g(X_2)) = H(f(X_1)) + H(g(X_2)|f(X_1))$$

so

$$H(f(X_1),g(X_1))-H(f(X_1),g(X_2))= H(g(X_1)|f(X_1)) - H(g(X_2)|f(X_1)) \leq 0.$$

You can also view $f(X,Y),g(X,Z)$ as a version of $f(X,Y),g(X,Y)$ that has been passed through a channel with additional randomness. By data processing, the inequality follows.

Comment: Thanks. Why $H(g(X_1) | f(X_1))\leq  H (g(X_2) | f(X_1))$

Comment: Because $g(X_2)$ and $f(X_1)$ are less correlated than $g(X_1)$ and $f(X_1)$.

Comment: Intuitively, yes. I don't know how to prove it rigorously. Or could you elaborate the idea of using  data processing? Thanks.

Comment: Well, consider the function $q(X,Y,Y)$ which has entropy of whatever. This is your left hand side. You have the exact same function $q$ on the right hand side, but with different arguments, $q(X,Y,Z)$. Now, if you know $X$ and $Y$, there's no uncertainty in $q(X,Y,Y)$. But there's still uncertainty in $q(X,Y,Z)$.

Comment: I agree. This means that $H(q(X,Y,Y) | X,Y)=0$ and $H(q(X,Y,Z) | XY)\geq 0$. From here ,how to derive that $H(q(X,Y,Y))\leq H(q(X,Y,Z))$? The inequality is true intuitively. I just wanna justify the intuition by a rigorous proof.